# Python: iterate over true and false variables in a list, with different outcomes

Tags: python, loops, iteration, iterable

I'm programming a yahtzee like game where a player rolls 5 dice and gets to pick which dice to re-roll.

I can't get my function to properly iterate over the user input verify that they are valid.

Here's some code:

```
def diceroll():
    raw_input("Press enter to roll dice: ")
    a = random.randint(1, 6)
    b = random.randint(1, 6)
    c = random.randint(1, 6)
    d = random.randint(1, 6)
    e = random.randint(1, 6)
    myroll.append(a)
    myroll.append(b)
    myroll.append(c)
    myroll.append(d)
    myroll.append(e)
    print "Your roll:"
    print myroll
    diceSelect()

def diceSelect():
    s = raw_input("Enter the numbers of the dice you'd like to roll again, separated by spaces, then press ENTER: ")    
    rollAgain = map(int, s.split())
    updateMyRoll(rollAgain)

def updateMyRoll(a):
    reroll = []
    for n in a:
        if n in myroll:
            reroll.append(n)
            removeCommonElements(myroll, a)
            print "deleting elements..."
        elif n not in myroll:
            print "I don't think you rolled", n, "."
            diceSelect()
        else:
            print "I don't understand..."
            diceSelect()
        print "Your remaining dice: ", myroll

def removeCommonElements(a,b,):
for e in a[:]:
    if e in b:
        a.remove(e)
        b.remove(e)
```

The problem is likely in the diceSelect function, such that I can enter only true values and it works fine, I can enter only false values and get the desired effect for ONLY the first false value (which I understand based on the code... but would like to change), or I can enter true AND false values but it ONLY acts on the true values but ignores the false values.

How can I iterate over these values and re-prompt the user to enter all true values?

Comment: What is the "desired effect"?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I apologize for being unclear, I'll update the original post.  I want it to verify that all values from the user match values that were actually in the original 5 dice rolled.  If they are not, I would like it to go back to prompting them to enter valid values.  This is the behavior that takes place when I enter only false values, however, it only tells the user 'I don't think you rolled x' for only the first false value entered.

Comment: Is there any reason that you're learning Python with Python2? These days you should be using Python3

Comment: @WayneWerner I suppose I should switch to Python3; I was referred to "Learn Python the Hard Way," which I found out uses Python2.  But I would like to get a new book for Python3.  I welcome any suggestions for a good resource.  I like more structure than LPTHW, but getting my hands dirty has been good.

Comment: With a bad value, you jump to `diceSelect()` before looking at any other values.  Consider collecting the bad values in a list, then give the error message with the full set of bad values after the loop completes.  Then call `diceSelect()`.

Comment: Yeah, using Python2 is one of the [many problems](https://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints) with that book. We have a [nice list of better resources](https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F)

Comment: @andrew_reece thank you; I will try this. Another issue I've had here has been if I call diceSelect() due to a bad value repeatedly, when I finally input only good values, it prints "Your Remaining Dice:" myroll, the multiple times at the end (equal to however many times diceselect() was called, but prints them all identically only after all values are true).

Comment: I recommend fully specifying the issue(s) you are trying to solve, along with the expected and actual results you're seeing.  That will make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple of problems here in your code. I've re-written your code a bit:

```
def diceroll(dice_count=6):
    raw_input("Press enter to roll dice: ")
    # No need to create a variable for each roll.
    # Also modifying global variables is a bad idea
    rolls = []
    for _ in range(dice_count-1):
        rolls.append(random.randint(1,6))
    # or **instead** of the above three lines, a list
    # comprehension
    rolls = [random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(dice_count-1)]
    return rolls

def roll_select():
    # one letter variable names are hard to follow
    choices = raw_input("Enter the numbers of the dice you'd like to roll again, separated by spaces, then press ENTER: ")    
    # again, modifying global variables is a bad idea
    # so return the selection
    return map(int, choices.split())

def roll_new_dice(myroll):
    # no need to create a new list, we have everything
    # we need right here
    for val in roll_select():
        try:
            print('deleting {}'.format(val))
            # we can just remove the values directly. We'll get
            # an exception if they're not in the list.
            myroll.remove(val)
        except ValueError:
            print("That wasn't one of your rolls")
    # Then we can re-use our function - this time
    # extending our list.
    myroll.extend(diceroll(6-len(myroll)))

rolls = diceroll()
print('You rolled {}'.format(rolls))
changes = roll_select()
if changes:
    roll_new_dice(rolls)
print('Your new rolls: {}'.format(rolls))
```

Hopefully this should be a bit clearer than what you had before.

Comment: Thank you very much, this  was so much more than I could have asked for.  I'm installing Python3 now and transitioning.  I'm looking at some of the resources posted for learning Python3; I don't mind purchasing a comprehensive book.  The official Python3 tutorial is good but not a great place for someone like me to start, but looks appropriate to go look up topics as I progress.